# Would a husband's tax rise if the wife is employed?

Tags: income-tax, germany

Would I pay more tax if my wife is employed?  I would be grateful for any advice?

Comment: I don't know the German tax system, but I would imagine you'd need to give much more detail for this to be answerable. In the UK, I think it would generally be unlikely (depending on how you defined "I"/"we"), but there could be edge cases, and there could be cases where you lose access to certain benefits which -- while not an increase in tax -- could make you (collectively) worse off.

Comment: @TripeHound You're wrong about the UK. You can now transfer £1,150 of your tax allowance to your spouse if you're not using it and they don't earn over £45,000. So you will in general pay less tax if your spouse is not employed.

Comment: @MikeScott Accepted, but can I hide behind "_how you define I/we_" and "_could be edge cases_" to make me not "wrong" but perhaps over-generalised? To me it just emphasises that the OP needs to provide more details to have a hope of a good response.

Answer (score 2):

If you are paying taxes as a married couple, the question 'would I pay more tax?' does not make much sense - you pay income tax together, and it doesn't matter from which salary they are taken.

If your spouse has an additional income, you - as a married couple - owe more taxes, and also progressively more (not just proportionally more).

During the year, you can choose if you want to have income tax withheld from each salary independently (choose classes 4/4), or unevenly (choose 3/5). This has no effect on the total amount you owe; and at the end of the year, you will have to pay the difference, or can get back what you overpaid.

Note that choosing 4/4 ensures you pay at least what you owe, but typically more, so you have to file income tax forms to get the overpayment back (if you don't, the state is happy to keep it). If you chose 3/5, it is possible (but not automatic) that you underpay; therefore, 3/5 always requires you to file.

Taking your question more literally: if you don't change your current class, the amount withheld will remain exactly the same - your employer will not know that your wife now has a salary. You *do* start owing more taxes, as your overall income has increased, but the taxes you owe are not what gets deducted from every paycheck - it is just an estimate.

Finally, note that whatever you do, additional income always results in more money for you, even after paying increased taxes.